Are the spring constant and damping coefficient of landing gear publicly available?
I'm trying to find the spring constant and damping coefficient for a Cessna 172. I looked through the POH, but couldn't find them anywhere. Are these values available publicly in some design document I'm not aware of? (I'm trying to determine the force needed for the plane to bounce.)
